# Finding the break in data from a piecewise function

Tags: java, statistics, linear-regression, astronomy

Greetings,

I'm performing research that will help determine the size of observed space and the time elapsed since the big bang. Hopefully you can help!

I have bilinear data on which I want to perform two linear regressions. There is a point at which the slope and intercept change, and I need to (write a program to) find this point.

Thoughts?

Comment: Might see if [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/index.html) would be useful to you

Comment: Match the data from the two ends with least squares. If you have decent data, your point will be by the intersection

Comment: You might also look at Total Variation filtering of the gradient image.

Answer (score 0):

There was a paper on this a few years ago by Joo and Qiu at Minnesota:
http://pubs.amstat.org/doi/pdf/10.1198/tech.2009.07163